# How are if statements processed?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to optimize my code as much as possible and that, to me, means minimizing the amount of calculations performed. I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Entities.Count; i++) 
{
    if (this.Entities[i].Type == 2)
    {
        if (this.Entities[i].X > this.Bounds.Width + this.SideOffset || this.Entities[i].X < -this.SideOffset)
        {
            this.Entities.Remove(this.Entities[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and to optimize it I have nested the out of bounds check inside the type check so it is only ran when the check is ran. My question is, how are if statements processed in C#? Is every condition checked regardless or could I put both if statements in one and have it effectively still run the same (If this.Entities[i].Type doesn't equal two it wouldn't run the rest of the if statement)

Comment: Not your answer, but you'd better to change the loop verse.

Comment: Makes no difference, the && operator already short-circuits and will not evaluate the right-hand side expression if the left one is false.  Do note the glaring bug in your code, you are modifying the collection you are iterating.  That will cause elements to be skipped.  You must iterate it backwards.

Comment: These are micro-optimizations. Consider doing something about the for loop instead.

Comment: What could I do to optimize it?

Comment: Use linq query and list's RomeveAll() method as i explained you in example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two types of `AND` and `OR` in C#:

`&`/`|` will always check both sides of condition.

> The & operator **evaluates both operators regardless of the first one's value**
>
> *from [`&` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)*

`&&`/`||` will not check right side if final result can be evaluated using left side only.

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but **only evaluates its second operand if necessary.**
>
> *from [`&&` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)*

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands. **If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated.**
>
> *from [`||` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)*

Answer (score 7):

C# performs short circuit logic when using `||` or `&&`

Your logic line:

```
 if (this.Entities[i].X > this.Bounds.Width + this.SideOffset || this.Entities[i].X < -this.SideOffset)
```

`this.Entities[i].X < -this.SideOffset` would not execute if the prior condition failed.

You could have made your logic:

```
if ( (this.Entities[i].Type == 2) && (this.Entities[i].X > this.Bounds.Width + this.SideOffset || this.Entities[i].X < -this.SideOffset)){
 ...
 }
```

However there is something to be said about read-ability over code that saves almost nothing in performance.  As in anything in coding, it all depends on context.